# how to upload files from browsers to private s3 bucket without serialization via a proxy

Tags: amazon-s3

we need to upload files from browsers to private s3 buckets, ideally without using signed url, the files are pretty big, up to 25GB or so, many terabytes of traffic are expected per week, but the files are very sensitive (medical imaging) and the uploads should be very controlled.

we were exploring the usage of nginx and a simple enough proxy but most things I'm finding ready made are too old and/or work for GET and HEAD (like the nginx s3 gateway) only, so no upload is possible afaik.

we would prefer to not provide even the signed url to the client browser, but because file sizes are big we would prefer to never serialize on the proxy server itself, not even chunks if it's possible.

would openresty and lua be an option for this? any options that you would think are better suited for the use case?

there is a nodejs webapp being built, but the best option we found through there provides signed urls to the client, if possible we would like for the client to point to a url that is not a direct s3 amazon url.

Answer (score 0):

This documented solution from AWS might fit your use case: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-s3-gateway-endpoint-proxy/blob/main/README.md

This uses Squid proxy behind an NLB to connect to S3. I believe you could ignore the aspects of the solution that involve VPN or Direct Connect (assuming your client will use this solution via the public internet).